# How could change style theme of actionbar in contextual menu mode

Tags: android, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

I am using toolbar with following style,

```
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

Style theme of Activity (AppCompatActivity) is

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

In this case I am getting Light theme (that to Activity) for action bar of "contextual  menu mode".

How could make style of the actionbar of the contextual menu mode to "DarkActionBar" without altering style of Activity (i.e. Theme.AppComapct.Light.NoActionBar)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve the requirement with following change in the style of Activity,

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/primaryDark</item>
</style>
```

The [link](http://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2014/10/28/android-changing-the-toolbars-text-color-and-overflow-icon-color/) help me into this and could be referred for more information.